# Prove that the intersection of balls ∩B(x,r) for r>0 is equal to {x}.

Tags: real-analysis

I have been struggling a bit with the proof for ∩B(x,r) ⊆ {x} for r>0.

One of the proofs presented to me was this one:

let y ∈ ∩B(x,r)

Want to show: y ∈ {x} i.e.  y = {x} i.e.  d(y,x)=0  i.e. ∀ε > 0: d(y,x) < ε.

Let ε > 0.

Want to show: d(y,x) < ε.

We have y ∈ ∩B(x,r) ⊆ B(x,ε) which gives d(y,x) < ε.

I am just not sure about why we can say that "y ∈ ∩B(x,r) ⊆ B(x,ε)" are we saying that ε is larger than r but also tending towards 0? Would appreciate an explanation or alternative proof. Thank you! (This is from a university course in Real and Abstract Analysis).

Comment: Try proof by contradiction. Suppose there is a $y$ not equal to $x$ that is in the intersection, and show that it is not in one of the balls.

Comment: it's interesting to see you calling them open balls in a real analysis course, but props to you nonetheless

Comment: The intersection of several sets is always a subset of every set being intersected.  $(A\cap C) \subset A$.  Always.  And $(A_1\cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap ..... )\subset A_i$.  Always.  So if $\epsilon >0$ then $B_{x, \epsilon}$ is one of the sets we are intersection when we intersect $\cap_{r>0} B_(x, \epsilon)$.  For *any* $r_0 > 0$ we we *always* have $\cap B(x,r) \subset B(x,r_0)$.  And if $r_0 = \epsilon > 0$ that holds.

Comment: "are we saying that ε is larger than r but also tending towards 0"  No, we are just saying  "$\epsilon > 0$ and $\cap B_(x,r)$ are all tne points that are in all the $B(x,r)$ were $r > 0$.  As $B(x,\epsilon)$ is *one* of those sets.  And $\cap B_(x,r)$ are the points in *all* of those sets then all the points of $\cap B_(x,r)$ are in $B(x,\epsilon)$ because $B(x,\epsilon)$ is *one* of those sets and $\cap B_(x,r)$ are the points in *all* of those sets.  ... Nothing is moving and $r$ isn't actually value.

Answer (score 1):

Like another user in the comments said, start with a collection open balls and assume there are two elements $x$ and $y$ in your intersection. This will cause a contradiction as we can find an $r$ such that $y$ is not in our intersection.

---

*Proof*

Let $r>0$ be given. Suppose you have a collection of open balls $B(x;r)=\{ b \in \mathbb{R} : |b-x|<r\}$ with center $x$.

Consider $\displaystyle\bigcap B(x;r)$. Since $x$ is our center, obviously, $x \in \displaystyle\bigcap B(x;r)$

Toward a contradiction, suppose there is also $y \in \displaystyle\bigcap B(x;r)$ such that $x \neq y$.

Since $x \neq y,$ $|x-y| >0$

Choose $r_\psi = |x-y|$

Then we can find $r_\tau$ such that $0<r_\tau < r_\psi$ in our collection of open balls

But then $y \not\in B(x;r_\tau)$. This is a contradiction since we assumed $x,y \in B(x;r)$ for all $r>0$

Thus, $\displaystyle\bigcap B(x;r) = \{x\} \hspace{1cm} \square$

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The first step is to fix an $\epsilon>0$. If $y\in \cap_{r>0}B(x,r)$, then in particular $y\in B(x,r)$ for every $r<\epsilon$. Remember that as soon as you write "Let $\epsilon>0$" that $\epsilon$ is now just a fixed number. It doesn't tend towards anything (namely zero) because it's fixed.

Comment: Sorry, I do not fully understand. I realize that epsilon is fixed I meant that I could make it as small as I want as long as it is larger than zero. But why can I assume that r < ?

Comment: We aren't trying to show that $\cap B(x,r) $ is one some Ball with a radius $r$ and that's a smaller radius the $\epsilon$.  $\cap B(x,r)$ is *not* any ball. It is the intersection of *ALL* balls.  And $B(x, \epsilon)$ is *one* of those balls.  There we will be some $r_i < \epsilon$ and there will be some $r_j > \epsilon$ and there will be *exactly* one $r_k = \epsilon$.  Note whatever is in *all* the balls will be in ... all the balls.  So it will be in $B(x,\epsilon)$.  But what is in all the balls will *not* actually be a ball itself.

Answer (score 0):

Forget the meaning of $B(x,r)$ and the relative sizes of $r, \epsilon$ or any other value.  The point they are making is just this:

> If $\cap_{r\in I} X_r$ is an intersection of so sets $X_r$ and $\epsilon \in I$ so $X_\epsilon$ is one of those sets;  then $\cap_{r\in I} X_r \subset X_\epsilon$.

Pf:

> If $y \in\cap_{r\in I} X_r$ then for any value of $r \in I$ we have $y \in X_r$.  So If $\epsilon$ is any possible value in $I$ we will have $y\in X_\epsilon$.  So $y \in\cap_{r\in I} X_r \implies y \in X_\epsilon$ so $\cap_{r\in I} X_r \subset X_\epsilon$.

That is all they are assuming and that is all that is relevant.

It is true (but not relevant) that if $r_0 < \epsilon < r_1$ then $B(x,r_0) \subset B(x,\epsilon) \subset B(x,r_1)$. And it is true (but not relevant) that if $\epsilon > 0$ then there is an $r_\omega < \epsilon$ and $B(x,r_\omega)\subset B(x,\epsilon)$.

None of that is what the proof is getting at.

The proof merely wants to say $(B(x,r_0)\cap B(x,r_1) \cap B(x,r_2)\cap ...\cap \color{red}{B(x, r_i)}\cap B(x,r_{i+1}).... \subset \color{red}{B(x, r_i)}$  for any $r_i > 0$.

That's all.

> [*Of course I just did a big abuse of notation. $(0, \infty)$ is no countable and I can't list the $r_i \in (0, \infty)$ one after another like that.  But it doesn't matter.  If we have $\cap_{r>0}B(x,r)$ is the intersection of all such balls, and $B(x,\epsilon)$ is one of the balls in question, then the intersect of all balls is a subset of any one of the balls.*]

So that's all.

What they are getting at is this:

If $y \in \cap B(x,r)$ and $\epsilon > 0$ then $y \in B(x,r)$ for all $r > 0$ including if we set $r = \epsilon > 0$.  So $y \in B(x,\epsilon)$ and $d(x,y) < \epsilon$.

But that means if $x \ne y$ then $d(x,y) > 0$ so if we set $d(x,y) = \epsilon > 0$ we get a contradiction that $d(x,y) < \epsilon = d(x,y)$.

So $x = y$.  So if $\cap B(x,r)$ is non-empty then $\cap B(x,r)=\{x\}$.

But $d(x,x) = 0 < r$ for all $r > 0$.  So $x \in B(x,r)$ for all $r > 0$. So $x \in \cap B(x,r)$.  So $\cap B(x,r)=\{x\}$.